# Angular2Firebase query by multiple values whereIN

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

So I'm looking for the equivalent of `WHERE IN(val1,val2)` I have tried like this but doesn't work.

Angular Firebase

```
this.firebase.database.list('/favorites', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'uID',
                equalTo: [1,2,3,'some value]
            }
});
```

Comment: Is the equalto you are after require an array of different values? equalto works with one value only.  This type of configuration. Requires you to setup your firebase differently. Would need to know what your trying to accomplish overall

Comment: My main goals is to query a set of users by id and list them, I'm trying to list the favorites businesses by the user, so that's why I need to query by multiple ids at once. So yeah different values @JesseTeWeehi

Comment: you should save the favorites under users node. then it will be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase's queries don't have an `OR` or `IN` operator. So you cannot easily map the above query to Firebase.

One workaround would be to implement **multiFilter** over the elements:

```
public items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]> = null;


ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.db.list('/favorites', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'uID'  
        }
    });

    this.items.subscribe(items => {
       console.info(this.multiFilter(items,{'uID': [1,2,3,'some value]}));
    });
}

public multiFilter(arr: Object[], filters: Object) {
  const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return arr.filter(eachObj => {
    return filterKeys.every(eachKey => {
      if (!filters[eachKey].length) {
        return true; // passing an empty filter means that filter is ignored.
      }
      return filters[eachKey].includes(eachObj[eachKey]);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Queries are created by building on the firebase.database.Reference.
Check the Doc:https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

```
  this.firebase.database.list('/favorites', {
    ref => ref.orderByChild('uID').equalTo(1,2,3,'some value)

   });
```

or

```
    constructorpublic af:AngularFireDatabase) {
             this.items = af.list('/messages', ref => 
               ref.orderByKey(true).equalTo(1,2,3,'some value));
        });
```

Comment: @Chellapan V https://screencast.com/t/5qIWwwC7XZx and https://screencast.com/t/HKEiP3ycP

Comment: @ChellappanV i think you answer should be editet to this.firebase.database.list('/favorites', ref => ref.orderByChild('uID').equalTo(1,2,3,'some value')); You have extra handlebars and a missing comma after some value. But you answer seems to be the good one

Answer (score 1):

I would have the users under a users node.

Generally the IDs would be the firebase pushKeys.

so user > userId > { user information }.

Then have businesses

business > businessId > { business information }

then a business to user node.

businessForUser > userId > businessId = true

So you would then fetch the list of businessIDs for the user from the businessForUser node and then fetch the business information from the business node with those fetched IDs.